# what does the activerecord circular reference error actually mean? and how do you fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've got a error from rails 
"ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::CircularReferenceError",

I'm not sure entirely what the error means when it says I have an object referencing itself. Can somebody explain that, and help me understand how to fix it?

The error comes from the following code. 
In my model,call

```
scope :search_wineries, lambda{|wineries|{:joins => :winery, :conditions =>["wineries.id IN (?)", wineries]}}
    scope :search_varietals, lambda{|varietals|{:joins => :varietals, :conditions => ["varietals.id IN (?)",varietals] }}
    scope :search_wines, lambda{|wines|{:conditions=>["wines.id IN (?)",wines]}}

    def self.search_wines(params)
        scope = self
        [:wineries,:varietals,:wines].each do |s|

            scope = scope.send("search_#{s}", params[s]) if !params[s].empty?
        end
        scope
    end
```

and this is called from my controller I call

```
return_wines = Wine.search_wines({wineries:wineries,varietals:varietals,wines:wines})
        render :json => return_wines.to_json(:include=>[:winery,:varietals])
```

Answer (score 2):

It usually means you are printing a model whose json model includes itself, usually through another model.

E.g. Consider these two classes

```
class Pet
  belongs_to :owner

  def as_json
    super(only: :name, include: :owner)
  end
end

class Owner
  has_many :pets
  def as_json
    super(only: :name, include: :pets)
  end
end
```

We can print each of them as json

```
o = Owner.new(name: "Steve")
o.as_json 
#=> { name: "Steve", pets: [] }

p = Pets.new(name: "Fido", owner: nil)
p.as_json 
#=> { name: "Fido", owner: nil } 

p.owner = o
o.as_json 
#=> FAILS with CircularReference error. Why?
```

Think about what it *should* produce.

```
o.as_json 
#=>
{ 
  name: "Steve",
  pets: [
    {
      name: "Fido",
      owner: {
        name: "Steve", # Uh oh! We've started to repeat ourselves.
        pets: [
          {
             name: "Fido",
             owner: ...and so on, and so on, forever recursing, because the models json representation *includes* itself.
           }
         ]
       }
     }
   ]
]}
```